# Calculating the delta over a single table

Tags: sql, database

How can I calculate the additions, deletions and modifications between two sets of data that lie in the same table? Here's an example:

```
drop table if exists people;
create table people (job int, id int, name varchar(255));

insert into people values (1, 1, "Amy");
insert into people values (1, 2, "Bob");
insert into people values (1, 3, "Chris");

insert into people values (2, 1, "Amy");
insert into people values (2, 2, "Robert");
insert into people values (2, 4, "Dennis");
```

In this example, Bob's name has changed to Robert, Chris has been deleted and Dennis has been added.

So far, I can get the additions:

```
select p2.* from people p1
right join people p2
on p1.job = 1
and p2.job = 2
and p1.id = p2.id
where p2.job = 2
and p1.id is null;
```

And I can get the deletions:

```
select p1.* from people p1
left join people p2
on p1.job = 1
and p2.job = 2
and p1.id = p2.id
where p1.job = 1
and p2.id is null;
```

But I'm not sure how to get the modifications.

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For you example data this will return the *modified*:

```
select * from people p1
join people p2
on p1.job = 1 
and p2.job = 2
and p1.id = p2.id         -- same id
WHERE p1.name <> p2.name  -- but different name
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out!

```
select * from people p1
join people p2
on p1.job = 1
and p2.job = 2
and p1.id = p2.id
where p1.name != p2.name;
```

It wasn't so bad, in the end.